# Programmatically scroll QScrollArea

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a Widget with QScrollArea in it and I want it to be scrolled down right after the widget containing it is shown. I tried:

```
scrollArea->ensureVisible(0,100, 20, 20);
```

It works only when invoked by user (pushing button for example). Putting it in widget contstructor or showEvent doesn't work. Can it be done automatically?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe you can scroll the QScrollArea content by setting positions to its horizontal and vertical scrollbars. Smth, like this:

```
scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->value() + 10);
scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->value() + 10);
```

code above should scroll contents of the scroll area 10 pixels down and 10 pixels right each time it gets called

hope this helps, regards

**Edit0**: extra code snippet showing how to scroll the area in the form's constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QLabel *imageLabel = new QLabel;
    QImage image("my_large_image_file.JPG");
    imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

    ui->scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    ui->scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);

    ui->scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(100);
    ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(100);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when invoked from widget constructor or showEvent, it doesn't work either.

Comment: I guess you should post up some of your code, as this solution works for me in my form's widget constructor

Comment: Ok, I found the bug.  Before setting scrollbars there was resize(maximumSize()), which is obviously not a good idea (however I'm not sure why that influenced scrollAreas behaviour in that way).

Answer (score 3):

I have spent some time with the debugger and find out that scriollArea has 0 sizes in the constructor, so it looks like it is possible to scroll something only when all the widgets are created and visible. Scrolling in the showEvent of window works fine.